# How to draw image from foreignObject in canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, svg, canvas

My xml code is the follow :

```
    svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400">' +
    '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
 '<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin:0px;white-space:pre;line-height:1;">' +            
    '<img src="foo.png" width="300" height="300" />' + 
    '</body>' +
    '</foreignObject>' +
    '</svg>';
```

I draw this svg in my canvas as follow :

```
data = encodeURIComponent(svg);

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

};

img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + data;
```

The problem is that the foo.png inside foreignObject is not drawn in the canvas.

So why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Thank you for the solution.